# Getting events of all levels using a non-root logger

Tags: python, logging

I have a non-root logger with some handlers attached, and I want the logger to pass every event to them, including events on user-defined levels - thus I did a `log.setLevel(NOTSET)`, [which is the lowest level (`0`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging-levels).

That, however, [makes the logger inherit the level of the parent (root) logger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel), which I don't want, since delivering those events to my handlers should be unconditional.

I'm wondering if `log.setLevel(1)` would be the right choice here. It doesn't seem elegant, so maybe there's another way of accomplishing this?

Here's a minimal example - it prints nothing, which is not what I want:

```
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, NOTSET
from sys import stdout

log= getLogger("mylogger")
handler= StreamHandler(stdout)
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(NOTSET)

log.debug("something")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing it the correct way: If you were only worried about handling built-in levels, you would use `log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` without a second thought. In this case you want to cover every possible user-defined level, which can be achieved using a level of 1. I don't think this is inelegant, the only difference between this and `log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` is there's no built-in constant for the level you're using. If it makes you feel better, you could define a constant that maps to 1 to clarify what you're doing:

```
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler
from sys import stdout

ALL_LEVELS = 1

log= getLogger("mylogger")
handler= StreamHandler(stdout)
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(ALL_LEVELS)

log.debug("something")
```

Comment: I mostly wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. That looks a bit better, thanks!